# htaccess php GET not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess doesn't work with GET. It displays "news/", but once I go "news/1" or "news/1/" it doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$    index.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^news/$ news.php
RewriteRule ^news$ news.php
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ news.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ news.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My PHP is:

```
if(!isset($_GET["id"])){
$Article->printArticles();
}else{
$Article->printArticle($_GET["id"]);
}
```

But it doesn't find the `$_GET["id"]` but at localhost it works.
Have tried with [L,QSA], [N], [NC,L] and without any of these.

How shall the htaccess look to find the `$_GET["id"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How shall the htaccess look to find the `$_GET["id"]`

This is most likely result of `MultiViews` option being ON on your web server.

Turn it off using this line at the top:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

[Option `MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/news` is the URL then Apache will serve `/news.php`.